# Strip unwanted data from a string when contained numbers can vary

Tags: php, substr

I have strings that could contain data such as:

- PMC 1 to 2 days
- PTG 10 to 15 days
- PTG 3 to 7 days
- Puckator 1 to 3 days

I need to strip this so that i am just left with the numbers stored as two separate variables which i can use as integers for longest delivery time calculation in another code section.
I'm assuming i need to use substr but i don't know if/how it can be used if you don't know what the value is that you want to strip.
Do i need to do a separate line for every possible first and second number?
And can the substr be combined to extract the first and second at the same time or will i need to handle it twice?

Comment: If you need something like this: stackoverflow.com/questions/11243447/get-numbers-from-string-with-php it will work

Comment: What are the rules for these strings?  It should be possible to get the two numerical values using regex.

Comment: @SurrealDreams Edited question to explain the use of the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with regular expressions and PHP's [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function:

```php
$str = "PTG 10 to 15 days";
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
print_r( $matches[0] );
// => Array
//    (
//        [0] => 10
//        [1] => 15
//    )
```

If you want to get them as individual variables, [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is your friend:

```php
list($first_num, $second_num) = $matches[0];
echo $first_num;  // => 10
echo $second_num; // => 15
```

Since you're new to regular expressions, I recommend reading the venerable [Regular-Expressions.info tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). In this case we used the regular expression `/\d+/`, which just says to match all sequences of one or more digits. `\d` means "digit" and `+` means "one or more" of whatever comes before it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. Thanks too for the link to the tutorial. Well worth reading.